# How to deal with a 1-1/4" trap on a pedestal sink

Tags: plumbing, drain

I have an older pedestal sink that was installed with a 1-1/4" P-trap (or maybe it is part of the sink?). Another plumber saw the wall fitting (not the fixture) was 1-1/4" and said that such a fitting was not to code and could cause a slow draining sink. When I told him it was a pedestal sink, he said that was probably the reason.

Do pedestal sinks have smaller diameter drains or something? Can I change it out to 2" pipe, or is that not possible with a pedestal sink?

Comment: Can you fit 2" pipe within the pedestal? That may be the reason for the smaller pipe.

Comment: I don't think 2" is required for bathroom sink. 1 1/4" tail piece to 1 1/2" trap to 1 1/2" adapter on the sanitary tee will be sufficient.